# Dragging a specific UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my code I have an array of objects which are UIImageViews with UIImages in them.

I use a for loop in `-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  to move all objects from the array one by one.

Once they are moved to different positions on the main view I would like to be able to grab any of those objects and move them somewhere else.

I'm not sure how best to do this.  Is there a way I can use touchesbegin so that I can drag only the item I clicked on?

Basically, there are five UIImageViews there now and each one has UIImage and I am trying to get to the point where when i click on any of them they are able to move around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar with great success using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in my draggable view.  To hook it up, it might look something like this:

```
@implementation DraggableView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   ...
   ...
   UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)] autorelease];
   [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
   ..
   return self;
}
@end
```

In your `pan:` method, you could check the state of the gesture and even capture the gesture's location and use it to relocate your view.  Here's a ***rough*** example of what it might look like:

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

   if (gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
   {
      //We're moving!
      UIView *aRootView = <perhaps your root view controller's view>;
      CGPoint currentOrigin = [gesture translationInView:aRootView];
      self.frame = CGRectMake(currentOrigin.x,currentOrigin.y,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.hight);
      ...
      ...
   }

}
```

[Here is more reading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: John Muchow posted this on a blog [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/drag-an-image-within-the-bounds-of-superview.html). You should be able to adapt for your own purposes.

```
//UIDraggableImageView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIDraggableImageView : UIImageView
{
    CGPoint currentPoint;
}

@end

//UIDraggableImageView.m
#import "UIDraggableImageView.h"

@implementation UIDraggableImageView

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage:image]) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // When a touch starts, get the current location in the view
    currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Get active location upon move
    CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    // Determine new point based on where the touch is now located
    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x + (activePoint.x - currentPoint.x),
                                   self.center.y + (activePoint.y - currentPoint.y));

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // Make sure we stay within the bounds of the parent view
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    float midPointX = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds);
    // If too far right...
    if (newPoint.x > self.superview.bounds.size.width  - midPointX)
        newPoint.x = self.superview.bounds.size.width - midPointX;
    else if (newPoint.x < midPointX)  // If too far left...
        newPoint.x = midPointX;

    float midPointY = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds);
    // If too far down...
    if (newPoint.y > self.superview.bounds.size.height  - midPointY)
        newPoint.y = self.superview.bounds.size.height - midPointY;
        else if (newPoint.y < midPointY)  // If too far up...
        newPoint.y = midPointY;

    // Set new center location
    self.center = newPoint;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding gesture recognizers to the views that you want to move, that way you can easily tell when they are tapped and you can use touchesMoved to move them around...

Answer (score -1):

On a button click add an image from camera roll to the imageview. Image can zoom in and out and should drag that image to any place in the view.

Comment: Please, make your answer step by step and add a code you already tried to your answer in able to be useful answer